# ¿Porqué algunos miembros de la comunidad, sobre todo los que sois bastante antigüos, hacéis a veces comentarios que merecerían ser respuestas?

Tags: discusión, preguntas, comentarios

Espero no molestar con mi pregunta, simplemente es que me llama mucho la atención.

Tampoco es que lleve mucho en la comunidad, y aún no me desenvuelvo con soltura, pero me sorprende a veces ver y leer comentarios en alguna pregunta tan elaborados, clarificadores y detallistas que a mi modo de ver, *merecerían ser buenas respuestas*.

Generalmente, lo soléis hacer los miembros antigüos y con mucha reputación, y no es que lo vea mal, ojo, cada uno ayuda a su manera y muchos de esos comentarios a veces tienen más calidad que algunas de mis respuestas.

Por lo único que me ha impulsado a realizar ésta pregunta, es por el echo, de al ser a veces tan clarificadores (los comentarios), de ellos los OP obtienen la respuesta que buscan y al final *se queda la pregunta abierta*.

El problema es que cuando abres la sección de preguntas sin contestar, vas abriendo pregunta a pregunta y una extensa mayoría de las mismas, como digo, están contestadas por medio de los comentarios, y a veces se hace difícil navegar por tantas y tantas buscando las que siguen abiertas que como digo, ya se han contestado en los comentarios.

Por otra parte, los que estamos aprendiendo día a día, con mucho esfuerzo y en cierto modo, con nuestras limitaciones por la dificultad que nos entraña la programación y su lógica, hablando ya de manera personal. me hace sentirme un poco envidioso de vuestro dominio en el tema y que en lugar de aprovechar la oportunidad e formular una respuesta, os limitéis a realizar los citados comentarios.

Con el trabajo que nos cuesta a los nuevos encontrar preguntas que podamos ser capaces de responder y sentirnos orgullosos de nosotros mismos por poner nuestro pequeño granito de arena en quitar una o varias dudas y ofrecer nuestra ayuda desinteresada o bien buscando un poco de reputación.

Un saludo y muchas gracias.

Comment: Uno no siempre tiene el tiempo y el ánimo para una respuesta completa.

Comment: Yo no soy tan antiguo y tampoco tengo tanta reputación, pero el sentido común, me indica que a veces no es necesaria la petulancia y vanagloria de una respuesta, siendo que un simple comentario resuelve el problema, saludos.

Comment: A veces es muy "obvia" o extremadamente sencilla la respuesta.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

En general, no se recomienda responder preguntas en comentarios. Se pide que siempre que se pueda, se arme una respuesta.

A titulo personal, es una regla que siempre trato de respetar. Lo que sucede muchas veces, es que la respuesta a preguntas elaboradas es simple o trivial, y armar una respuesta de 5 líneas no lleva a nada.

Muchas otras veces, las preguntas parecen elaboradas, pero son confusas, y con uno o dos comentarios se da con el problema planteado. Otra vez, una respuesta de 2 líneas no es algo que me guste.

El sitio permite siempre autoresponderse, y muchas veces, esas preguntas que fueron contestadas en comentarios, podrían ser autorespondidas, demostrando que se aprendió y que se puede enseñar a otros.

A veces, uno solo sabe la respuesta, y soluciona el problema rápidamente pero no puede tomarse el tiempo de armar una respuesta completa... Y además, ayudar a aprender por si mismo también es una forma de enseñar...

Answer (score 17):

Es complicado dar una respuesta genérica, así que explico mi razonamiento:

- Cuando tienes mucha experiencia aprendes a identificar escenarios y problemas comunes que suelen atascar a los novatos.
- Si el problema se puede generalizar, tiendo a poner una respuesta que pueda ayudar a más gente que al OP, explicando con detalle el asunto.
- Si el problema es algo que considero "trivial" (el clásico escenario que una vez que sabes qué pasa te parece evidente la solución y además la solución es muy simple), tiendo a pensar que no vale la pena gastar mi tiempo en exponer la solución en una respuesta y prefiero poner un comentario para poner al OP sobre la pista correcta.

Obviamente esta forma de actuar tiende a acentuarse cuando tienes tanta reputación que has ganado todos los privilegios que el sitio otorga por la misma (20K, si no recuerdo mal), así que si el propio OP o cualquier otro usuario transforma mi comentario en una respuesta con los detalles necesarios  pues tendrá mi voto por ahorrarme el trabajo.

Como efecto secundario esto puede fomentar la participación de otros usuarios no tan veteranos: escribir una respuesta y que sea aceptada es especialmente agradable durante tus primeros pasos en cualquiera de las comunidades de SE

Comment: Es encomiable que dejes espacio para que otros puedan participar y ganar reputación.

Comment: Tienes razón, en algunas ocasiones he tomado los comentarios para poder dar una respuesta.

Answer (score 2):

Depende del Escenario, muchas veces las preguntas suelen estar basadas en Opiniones o escenarios muy amplios. pero al revisar la estructura del post y su contenido no vale la pena cerrarle.

Entonces los más viejos suelen saber por dónde vienen este tipo de post y preferimos explicar en los comentarios como resolverlo, sin necesidad de cerrar la pregunta o plantear una respuesta a una pregunta que no cumple al 100% los requisitos mínimos.

En otras ocasiones, las preguntas son sobre errores de lógica, documentación o sintaxis... en donde no vale la pena dar una respuesta cuando esta respuesta puede ser una coma mal puesta...

incluso recomendamos al OP una vez encontrado la respuesta a estos problemas de sintaxis borrar la pregunta...